# Combine multiple elements with Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

This is the HTML I'm trying to combine:

```
<div class="post linkDetail">
  <div class="postThumbnail">
    <a href="/redirect?url=http%3A//blogs.msdn.com/archive/2012/04/23/how-to-improve-performance-in-your-metro-style-app.aspx">
      <img src="<validURL Here>" width="280">
    </a>
  </div>
  <p class="full-url">
    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/03/how-to-improve-performa...
  </p>
  <p></p>
  <p>Nobody likes slow or unresponsive apps. Users expect that apps respond immediately to touch,   taps, clicks, gestures and key-presses. Users expect that animations are smooth, that they can play, pause and restart their music and videos quickly, and that they never have to wait for the app to catch up with them. This is the first in a series of posts on how to make your apps "fast and fluid."    
   </p>
   <p>We invested a lot of time in the engineering teams thinking about how we can ensure the performance of Metro style apps. We have learned what we can do in the platform to deliver on fast and fluid performance and have also learned what works and what does not work in building apps that deliver great experiences. In this blog I share with you some of the hard lessons from our own experiences so that you can build the best possible experiences for your customers.</p><p>Performance is more than just a stopwatch and efficient algorithms. When I think of performance, I like to take a holistic ...
   </p>
</div>
```

I want to take all of the `<p>` content after the `p.full-url` element and combine all of the `<p>` elements into single text string.

So that this:

```
  <p></p>
  <p>Nobody likes slow or unresponsive apps. Users expect that apps respond immediately to touch,   taps, clicks, gestures and key-presses. Users expect that animations are smooth, that they can play, pause and restart their music and videos quickly, and that they never have to wait for the app to catch up with them. This is the first in a series of posts on how to make your apps "fast and fluid."    
   </p>
   <p>We invested a lot of time in the engineering teams thinking about how we can ensure the performance of Metro style apps. We have learned what we can do in the platform to deliver on fast and fluid performance and have also learned what works and what does not work in building apps that deliver great experiences. In this blog I share with you some of the hard lessons from our own experiences so that you can build the best possible experiences for your customers.</p><p>Performance is more than just a stopwatch and efficient algorithms. When I think of performance, I like to take a holistic ...
   </p>
```

Becomes:

Nobody likes slow or unresponsive apps. Users expect that apps respond immediately to touch,   taps, clicks, gestures and key-presses. Users expect that animations are smooth, that they can play, pause and restart their music and videos quickly, and that they never have to wait for the app to catch up with them. This is the first in a series of posts on how to make your apps "fast and fluid."     We invested a lot of time in the engineering teams thinking about how we can ensure the performance of Metro style apps. We have learned what we can do in the platform to deliver on fast and fluid performance and have also learned what works and what does not work in building apps that deliver great experiences. In this blog I share with you some of the hard lessons from our own experiences so that you can build the best possible experiences for your customers. Performance is more than just a stopwatch and efficient algorithms. When I think of performance, I like to take a holistic ...

**Is this possible in Simple HTML DOM?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used simple html dom, but I think this is what you need:

```
$result = '';
foreach($html->find('p') as $p) {
   $result .= strip_tags($p->plaintext);
}
```